# Spark cluster - read network shared directory

Tags: apache-spark

We ae trying to read a folder from network shared directory using spark cluster, but it says folder doesnt exist, but it works when its local mode. Can you please tell us how can we access? Do we need to move to hdfs to store file?

Answer (score 1):

When running Spark in local mode you start everything (the driver and all executor processes) on the machine where you start your Spark process. This means all tasks will see the file system of exactly this host. If the tasks access a directory on this host everything works fine.

If you start Spark in a cluster each executor node has its own filesystem and the tasks running on each executor node see the file system of their respective host. You *could* try to mount your network drive to exactly the same path on each executor node and things might work. However using a real distributed file system like HDFS will work better.